# How to using django-taggit in DRF

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-taggit

I am having trouble to serialize the tags from django-taggit. 
I followed the instruction from [here](http://blog.pedesen.de/2013/07/06/Using-django-rest-framework-with-tagged-items-django-taggit/), but it is outdated.

Here is what I did:

## views.py

```
class TagsSerializer(serializers.WritableField):

    def from_native(self, data):
        if type(data) is not list:
            raise ParseError("expected a list of data")
        return data

    def to_native(self, obj):
        if type(obj) is not list:
            return [tag.name for tag in obj.all()]
        return obj
```

I got this error :

> 'module' object has no attribute 'WritableField

Apparently the WritableField is deprecated.

I am using django 1.8, DRF 3.2 and django-taggit-0.17.

Comment: Here's a library you could use, https://github.com/glemmaPaul/django-taggit-serializer. For DRF > 3.0 you can use serializers.ListField.

Comment: @dev-jim there is no writable fields in DRF 3.2. Can you follow this link http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#composite-fields

Answer (score 7):

I would use the TaggableManager to update the tags, with a custom ListField to handle the serialisation of tags. Then you can use the serializer create/update methods to set the tags.

## serializers.py

```
class TagSerializerField(serializers.ListField):
    child = serializers.CharField()

    def to_representation(self, data):
        return list(data.values_list('name', flat=True))

class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializerField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
        instance = super(TagSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        instance.tags.set(*tags)
        return instance
```

or you can use the perform_create/perform_update hooks in the view.

## views.py

```
class TagView(APIView):
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        instance = serializer.save()
        if 'tags' in self.request.DATA:
            instance.tags.set(*self.request.DATA['tags'])
```